# How does open() have two definitions, as shown in the man-page?

Tags: c, system-calls

The man page of `open()` shows open has two definitions.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int open(const char *pathname, int flags);
int open(const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode);
```

I was trying to make a wrap around open to add a backtrace for some debugging. The definition in `fnctl.h` shows it as a variable argument function

```
int open(const char *path, int oflag, ... );
```

But how can I know whether mode is present or not?

Comment: Talking about tracing and debugging, most POSIX systems have something similar to [`strace`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) in Linux, which can be used to trace system calls and their arguments.

Answer (score 1):

The `mode` argument is not needed for all open flags. For example, if opening an existing file for reading, there's no need to set the file mode flags. On the other hand, when creating a file, you need to include the mode.

See [the documentation for `open`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) (or your local manual page) to see if you need to include the argument or not.

Comment: But as I mentioned, I am writing a wrapper around open. So I am looking for a solution to pass the mode as most of the places, where open is used, uses mode.

Comment: @user2647717 And I'm telling you to read the documentation on when and where the extra argument is used. Or are you wondering about how to define your wrapper function? Why not do it just the same way, using ellipsis (`...`) and then check the second argument if you should get the mode flags or not. (You might then want to read e.g. [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/variadic) on variadic functions.)

Comment: This is what I am trying to do. I don't want to change the behavior or open. I just want to add a backtrace to see the stack trace, which is not shown in strace.

So who ever calls  open with 3 arguments, I want to call with 3 arguments with a back trace and who ever calls with 2 arguments. So I want to know how many parameters are there as like printf is deriving it from format string. But I dont know how to derive it for open

Comment: @user2647717 There's no way to tell, inside the function at run-time, how many arguments were passed. You really have to check the second argument to know if the third argument is there or not. That's what the actual `open` function does.

Comment: @user2647717  Carefully read the manual . It is mentioned flag argument control how file is opened .

Answer (score 1):

[`open()`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Opening-and-Closing-Files.html) function -

```
int open (const char *filename, int flags[, mode_t mode])
```

`mode` is only used when file is created. No need when file is already  present but it won't affect also in either way .

Answer (score 1):

If flags include `O_CREAT`, there must be a third argument (mode). If not, or if the file already exists, the third argument (if supplied) will be ignored.

Since `open` is actually variadic, you can call it with any number of arguments (>2), but they will have no effect on the operation.

You will need to extract the mode argument using `stdarg.h`. The C variadic function feature does not provide any mechanism for a function to find out how many arguments it was called with, so all you can do is check the flag.